# Error when trying to publish in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

when i try to publish sonar through Jenkins i get below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project HEP06_R2_ServiceAuthorization: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: It is related to Java versions at compilation and runtime like described in your link Jens but probable reason is different.

Comment: give us you sonarque version !!!
and JDK version

Answer (score 0):

Since SonarQube 5.6, only Java 8 can be used to execute a project analysis (But Java 7 can still be used for the compilation).
See the [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) documentation for more information.